# Javascript / jQuery: Why do I keep getting undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<a class="tabTitle" id="title_boxtab_default" tab-type="default" href="#tabs-3">Sample</a>
```

In jQuery I'm trying to get the value of the href attribute with:

```
$('.tabTitle').last().attr('href');
```

But it keeps telling me it's undefined?

I should mention that the number of links with class"tabTitle" increases. That's why I use .last()

Comment: whether your script is running on dom ready handler

Comment: Nothing wrong with your script

Comment: What is undefined? `$`, `$('.tabTitle')`, `$('.tabTitle').last()` or `$('.tabTitle').last().attr('href')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Make sure you are running the script when the element is present in the DOM, f.ex using `.ready()`:

```
$(function() {
    alert( $('.tabTitle').last().attr('href') );
});
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/IyeSacU/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me in JSFiddle. I changed it to this, and it returned `#tabs-3`:

```
alert($('.tabTitle').last().attr('href'));
```

My guess is that it's not running from a ready handler like this:

```
$(function() {
    var x = $('.tabTitle').last().attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try DOM Ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tabTitle').last().attr('href');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZF85s/)